# Coldfusion:-Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost

Tags: coldfusion

I installed Coldfusion 8 trial version on my system (XP Professional sp3). I created an Folder in the “C:/Coldfusion8/wwwroot” called “buildProject” containing an Index.cfm and some other .cfm files.

But I am unable to access the Neither my project files or CFIDE/Administrator

I tried the following URLS

```
http://localhost:8500/wwwroot/buildProject/ 
http://localhost:8500/CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm
http:// 127.0.0.1:8500/wwwroot/buildProject/ 
http:// 127.0.0.1:8500/CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm
http://localhost /wwwroot/buildProject/index.cfm
http://localhost /CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm
http://localhost /wwwroot/buildProject/ 
http://localhost /CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm
```

Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1:8500.

- The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few
    moments.
- If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network
    connection.
- If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure
    that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

• I cleared the browsing “History” from both IE and FF. • I have restarted the CF server in the Control Panel >Administrative Tools > Services • Even restarted the IIS

Getting the same error.

Further I was trying to access IE/FF via CFbuilder But still I am getting the error “The connection was refused when attempting to contact [URL].”
My inetpub is in the D rive 
where as CF8 is in C drive 
Also when i check IIS-5 Control Panel  >Admin tools > Services
I do not find the Localhost under web sites or FTP sites.
Kindly help me with a fix.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed with the built in web server you would access your pages at

```
http://localhost:8500/buildProject/index.cfm
```

If you chose IIS as your web server it would be at

```
http://localhost/buildProject/index.cfm
```

assuming you are running IIS on default port 80